# Raw filter with ternary operator for html class attribute

Tags: html, css, attributes, twig

I've been trying to figure out how to stop Twig escape the following code, which I feel is a little nicer with the succinct ternary operator.

Hoping someone can confirm I'm using the correct syntax and if there are any performance hits doing it like this in my `_layout.twig` file:

```
<body{{ bodyClass is defined ? (' class="' ~ bodyClass ~ '"')|raw : '' }}>
```

And including in my `_template.twig` file:

```
{% extends "_layout" %}

{% set bodyClass   = 'Home' %}
```

Seems to work and is the only way I've managed to get proper output so far!

Comment: If it's working then this question is more appropriate on [codereview.se].

Comment: @JimGarrison Ah, sorry I don't post much here. Will add it there then thanks.

Comment: @JimGarrison Seems like [I'm not wanted there either](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/113857/twig-raw-filter-with-ternary-operator-for-html-class-attribute?noredirect=1#comment210876_113857) :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks good to me about the syntax and the performance.

This code, in Twig 1.23.1, compiles to:

```
 echo "<body";
 echo ((array_key_exists("bodyClass", $context)) ?
     (((" class=\"" . (isset($context["bodyClass"]) ? 
        $context["bodyClass"] : null)) . "\"")) : (""));
 echo ">";
```

As you can see,

- no exotic code, nothing that will slow down your code
- no escaping around any of the compiled code so your result will be raw

But that's a security nightmare, if `bodyClass` contains arbitrary code, it will be possible to inject anything to the dom, [for example, this](http://twigfiddle.com/9k5y6z).

By the way, I take this opportunity to remind that `class="{{ bodyClass }}"` is not safe enough using the default escaping strategy, using `{{ bodyClass | e('html_attr') }}` is safer.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Alain, appreciate it. On the topic of security, could you please elaborate? I'm using Craft CMS so the template code is sat under server root `/craft` and `/html` is rendered by the template. So presumably, this couldn't be accessed in any way via the browser if it's a `_partial.twig` file. I've updated my code to give better context. I had a look at the Twig attribute stuff, but to be honest I couldn't wrap my head around it (the function at least)

Comment: It depends on who sets the `bodyClass` variable. If that's you, everything is ok. If that's a user, you should consider escaping. By the way, are you sure your classes can contain html entities? I'm unsure about the explicit `|raw`. Enjoy anyway.

Comment: Ah, I see. The user definitely won't be going anywhere near the html templates so sounds like I'm good. I think [Craft](https://craftcms.com) has me covered there. If I'm understanding you correctly, the class attribute wouldn't contain any html entities, it's string interpolation. I've just found out [there are a few ways to do this with Twig](http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/201/3888) (Python `%s` format looks worth a try)